# sheet.cssRules throws error on inner pages but works fine on homepage

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, dom

I am using this function in my Wordpress site's custom javascript.

```
var addRule = (function (sheet) {
    if(!sheet) return;
    return function (selector, styles) {
        console.log(sheet.cssRules)
        if (sheet.insertRule) return sheet.insertRule(selector + " {" + styles + "}", sheet.cssRules.length);
        if (sheet.addRule) return sheet.addRule(selector, styles);
    }
}(document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1]));
```

The problem here is the above function works fine on homepage but,

Throws `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules` on inner pages.

Here is the link to my site,

[Homepage](https://zen3.signiminds.com/)  `//here you will see no error in console`

[Inner Page](https://zen3.signiminds.com/human-in-the-loop/speech/) `//here you will see an error in console`

as per my research, this error is caused by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS),
but why it is working on Homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt that the problem is caused by CORS. I suggest you to `console.log(document.styleSheets)` and see the `href` of the element to check which stylesheet is getting passed to your addrule() after doing this `document.styleSheets.length - 1`,  the stylesheet's href should be same as your domain.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to work without you including "../" before the sheet.cssRule. Just go ahead and count the depth of your internal file and add "../" to be exactly equal to that value.

Writing something like "../../../../sheet.cssRule" instead of "sheet.cssRule" should get the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you code is absolutely fine when we compare both pages and also try close console.log with (;) semi colon in your script.

```
console.log(sheet.cssRules);
```